# Find matrix of $T(z) = (4 + 9i)z$ for basis $\{2 + 2i, 2 + 4i\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we find the matrix $A$ of the linear transformation $T(z) = (4 + 9i)z$ from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$ with respect to the basis $\{2 + 2i, 2 + 4i\}$?

Comment: what have you tried? The question is wrong btw because $\{2+2i,2+4i\}$ is not a basis of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Presumably he meant an $\Bbb R$ basis, since it *is* an $\Bbb R$ basis for $\Bbb C$. Concerns like this are more constructively expressed as "did you really mean such-and-such?" rather than "your question is wrong."

Comment: An $\mathbb{R}$ Basis contains no $i$ ...

Comment: It certainly can.  For example $\{1, i\}$ is the standard $\mathbb R$-basis and it contains an $i$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis why do you think it's not a basis?

Comment: Do you want both the basis in image and domain to be $\mathcal{B} = \{ 2 +2i, 2+4i \}$? If not just apply the transformation to the basis vectors and make them your columns. Else you will need to look at the image of the basis vectors and find the linear combination of the basis vectors that forms that image.

Comment: @Kaster $\mathbb{C}$ is a 1 dimensional vectorspace of $\mathbb{C}$  , the basis has 2 elements  as i did have linear algebra we did make a difference between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$, and we learned that $\mathbb{R}$ vector spaces contains elements of $\mathbb{R}$ not of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis $\mathbb C$ is two dimensional :)

Comment: @Kaster i am pretty sure $\mathbb{C}$ is a 1 dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ vector space$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I don't think it's quite right to say that $\Bbb R$ vector spaces "contain elements of $\Bbb R$" but they do consist of n-tuples of elements from $\Bbb R$. $\Bbb C$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb Q$. Over the first it has dimension 2, over the second it has dimension 1, over the third it has infinite dimension. The dimensions change because you are allowed to use coefficients from bigger and bigger fields. More coefficients means lower dimension.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Kaster should have wrote "two dimensional over $\Bbb R$".

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, if you construct your complex number as $x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are both real, then it's two dimensional vector space over $(x,y)$ pair.

Comment: @rschwieb thats what i am talking about, when we say it consist of $n$-tuples of elements from $\mathbb{R}$ than $i$ can't be in any $\mathbb{R}$ vectorspace. And at Kaster, yeah you have the pair (x,y) and NOT (x, iy) thats what i am talking about ...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis how to write a basis of two vectors? Is notation $\{a,b\}$ valid? I think so. What is $a$? $a = 2 + 2i$, what is $b$? $b = 2 + 4i$, so you can write $\{2+2i, 2+4i\}$, so I ask you again, why do you think that is not a basis?

Comment: But there is a cononical correspondence that I don't think is not unreasonable to transfer between freely. It should be completely fine to write $(x, y)$ or $(x+iy)$ as a basis vector depending on context of the situation.

Comment: @Kaster I think this goes to much off topic, I am in the chat if you like to discuss

Comment: @DominicMichaelis It doesn't have to contain $i$: the usual model of $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ is just that it is the Cartesian product with funny multiplication. You identify $a+bi$ with $(a,b)$ in the Cartesian product. In particular $(0,1)^2=(-1,0)$. There is no $i$ written there because it is being represented by $(0,1)$.

Comment: @rschwieb i passed my linear algebra with nearly 100 % :) I just wanted to point out, that there is a difference between $a+b i$ and $(a,b)$ even though as Sean said, there is a canonical correspondence

Comment: @DominicMichaelis A formal difference, yes, but that difference is beside the point here.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis There's absolutely no difference between $a+bi$ and $(a,b)$ if you specify that $a+bi = (a,b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let v_1 and v_2 be your basis vectors then row reduce the left and you answer is on the right:

$$\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \ v_2 \ | \ T(v_1) \ T(v_2) \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

$T(2+2i) = (4 + 9i)(2 + 2i) = -10 + 26i$

$T(2+4i) = (4 + 9i)(2 + 4i) = -28 + 34i$

So you now know $TB^{-1}$.  Compute $BTB^{-1}$ to find $[T]_B$ where $B^{-1}$ is the basis in a matrix as columns, the inverse matrix to the change of basis matrix $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are building your 2-by-2 matrix $M$ so as to multiply with 1-by-2 row vectors of real numbers.

In this setup, your first basis vector has coordinates $[1,0]$ and the second $[0,1]$.

When you multiply $[1,0]M$ and $[0,1]M$ you should get the coordinates of their images, respectively.

Getting the value of their images is not hard: compute $(2+2i)(4+9i)$ and $(2+4i)(4+9i)$.

The next step would be to write these two images as linear combinations of your two basis vectors, and then arrange the coefficients in $M$ correctly to model the transformation.

I purposefully omitted the details of the last part because these are steps you really need to carry out yourself so that you can get the hang of how transformations are expressed as matrices. I think the rest of what I wrote gives a complete roadmap!